# $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=e^x-x$. Prove $e^{x^2}+e^x \ge x^2+x+2$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=e^x-x$.

The previous question asks for the image of $f(x)$, so all the possible output values.

$e^{x^2}+e^x \ge x^2+x+2$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$

Rearranging the terms I get:
$e^x-x \ge -(e^{x^2}-x^2) + 2$
$f(x) \ge -(e^{x^2}-x^2)+2$

For the right part of the equality I think maybe it would help to note $x^2=t, t\ge 0$ then it becomes:
$-f(t)+2$ for $t\ge0$.

Now, I know what the graph of function $f$ looks like because I was asked to find its image for the previous question: It is $[1,\infty)$. The image of $-f(t)$ must then be $(-\infty,-1]$ and when we add the leftover $2$ it becomes $(-\infty,1]$ so it is clear that the equality is true:

$[1,\infty)\ge(-\infty,1]$

I want to know if this is a good way of solving this exercise and also how would you solve it using less words, or in a more "mathematical" way I should say.

Comment: Note that $f''(x)>0$ and so the function is convex. Also $f'(x)=0$ has solution $x=0$. So $f(x) >1$. Should be easy from here ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I have an idea of how the graph of $f(x)$ looks like, I've drawn it when I calculated the image of the function. I don't see how the fact that it is convex helps us in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $e^x \geq x +1$ for any $x$ and if we replace $x$ by $x^2$, we obtain again $e^{x^2} \geq x^2 + 1 $. Adding up gives $e^x + e^{x^2}  \geq x^2 + x + 2 $ as was to be shown.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @radugabriel This is precisely what I wrote in my comment to which you replied that my comment did not help in any way.  You must be conflicted.  And if my comment were rhetorical, then it would have been useful.

Comment: Mark are you aware that the phrasing you use is different? As the asker pointed out in the comments, your reply is rather rhetorical

Comment: @james Do you know the definition of rhetorical?

Answer (score 0):

Recall Taylor series: $e^t=1+t+R_n(t)$, where $R_n(t)$ is the remainder. From here we have $$e^{x^2}+e^x\ge (1+x^2)+(1+x)=x^2+x+2\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb R$$